# Understanding behaviour of recursive code

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm going through the old question papers of a test I'm scheduled to answer in a few weeks and the following problem had me stymied:

A finite sequence of bits is represented as a list with values from the set {0,1} - for example, [0,1,0], [1,0,1,1].

[ ] denotes the empty list, and [b] is the list consisting of one bit b. For a nonempty list l, **head(l)** returns the first element of l, and **tail(l)** returns the list obtained by removing the first element from l.

**a:l** denotes a new list formed by adding a at the head of list l.

For example:

• head([0,1,0]) = 0, tail([0,1,0]) = [1,0],

• head([1]) = 1, tail([1]) = [ ], and

• 1:[0,1,0] = [1,0,1,0].

Consider the following functions:

• **f1** takes as input a list and returns another list.

```
f1(s):
 if (s == []) then return([1])
  else if (head(s) == 0) then return(1:tail(s))
  else if (head(s) == 1) then return(0:f1(tail(s)))
 endif
```

• **f2** takes as input a bit and a list and returns a bit.

```
f2(b,s):
 if (s == []) then return(b)
  else if (head(s) == 0) then return(f2(not(b),tail(s)))
  else if (head(s) == 1) then return(not(b))
 endif
```

• **g1** takes as input a nonnegative number and returns a list.

```
g1(n):
 if (n == 0) then return([0])
  else return f1(g1(n-1))
 endif
```

• **g2** takes as input a nonnegative number and returns a bit.

```
g2(n):
 if (n == 0) then return(0)
  else return f2(g2(n-1),g1(n))
 endif
```

1. What is the value of g2(7) and g2(8)?
2. What is the value of g2(256) and g2(257)?

---

So far I've only been able to understand the behavior of **f1**(replaces head by 1, if it is 0 and returns. Else, replace head by 0 and call itself on the rest of the list.), and **g1(n)** which is the same as **f1** applied to [0] **n** times(f1(f1(...f1([0]))) - n times).

Is there some structured method with which one can solve this and similar problems?(Especially under time pressure.)

EDIT: **f2** inverts bit **b** as many times as the number of **0's** before the first **1** in the **list s**.

**g2()** is still a mystery.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't call this code *obfuscated* nor is it pseudocode. The point of this exercise is to read the code and be a human computer. The trick is that you won't have to do all 256 or 257 loops once you see how the computation is working. You just have to start evaluating, observe a pattern, then basically skip to the end.

Comment: @changed The problem is this is a question on an exam and it is not feasible to test a large number of inputs, as the time available is at most 30 minutes(at best).

Comment: A good start would be to work through these answers yourself, no matter how slow or infeasible it is to do this in the exam. There's no magic trick, you just have to practice until it gets faster.

Comment: Reading your answer, you don't understand `f1`, you've merely put the code into words. You have to see the pattern and generalize what it's doing. But sorry, there's still no trick to doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paper & pen evaluation**

The best way to do this is to just start. Get the definitions of the functions in front of you and start your pen & paper evaluation. The question asks us to compare `g2(7)` and `g2(8)`, but looking at `g2` we see we need to understand `f2` and `g1` so let's start there. Because `g1`'s value is computed first, we'll familiarise ourselves with `g1` first

I'm just gonna start shoving some values into it and get the results. I'll start with `0` because, after looking at `g1`, that seems like the easiest to compute

```
g1(0) => [0]

g1(1) => f1(g1(0)) => ... stop, do not recompute `g1(0)` here, we already know the answer above
      => f1([0])
      => [1]

g1(2) => f1(g1(1)) => we already know `g1(1)` from above
      => f1([1])
      => 0 : f1([])
      => [0,1]

g1(3) => f1(g1(2)) => we already know `g1(2)`
      => f1([0,1])
      => [1,1]

g1(4) => f1(g1(3)) => reuse `g1(3)`
      => f1([1,1])
      => 0 : f([1]) => we already know `f1([1])`
      => 0 : [0,1]
      => [0,0,1]
```

Already I see a pattern here. Do you? `g1` is generating the binary sequence of 1s and 0s for `n` in [little endian bit order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness)

```
g1(0) => [0]
g1(1) => [1]
g1(2) => [0,1]
g1(3) => [1,1]
g1(4) => [0,0,1]
g1(7) => ?
g1(8) => ?
```

My guess is going to be `[1,1,1]` and `[0,0,0,1]` respectively. Let's keep going to see if we're right...

```
g1(5) => f1(g1(4))
      => f1([0,0,1])
      => [1,0,1]

g1(6) => f1(g1(5))
      => f1([1,0,1])
      => [0,1,1]

g1(7) => f1(g1(6))
      => f1([0,1,1])
      => [1,1,1]

g1(8) => f1(g1(7))
      => f1([1,1,1])
      => 0 : f([1,1]) => we already know f1([1,1])
      => 0 : [0,0,1]
      => [0,0,0,1]
```

**Making good progress**

Hey, our guess was correct! It should take you about 30-45 seconds to evaluate each of g(0) through g(8) – that's about 5.5 minutes and we have a pretty good understanding how `g1` and `f1` are working. We understand `g1` a little better because we know it just takes a number and spits out the binary sequence of bits to represent the input number. `f1` is sort of magical in *how* exactly it's working, but the cool part about this is it doesn't matter – the question asks us to compare values of `g2`, so as long as we can compute values of `g2` it doesn't matter if we have a terrific understanding of the other functions.

Last time evaluating `g1` gave us some valuable insight on `f1` and it looks like that's the same case for `g2` related to `f2`. Now that we have some values of `g1` that we can reference, let's try to compute some values of `g2` – I'll start with `0` like we did last time

```
g2(0) => 0

g2(1) => f2(g2(0),g1(1)) => we already know `g2(0)` and `g1(1)`
      => f2(0, [1])
      => 1

g2(2) => f2(g2(1), g1(2)) => we already know these!
      => f2(1, [0,1])
      => f2(0, [1])
      => 1

g2(3) => f2(g2(2), g1(3))
      => f2(1, [1,1])
      => 0

g2(4) => f2(g2(3), g1(4))
      => f2(0, [0,0,1])
      => f2(1, [0,1])
      => f2(0, [1])
      => 1
```

At this point, I don't see *much* of a pattern yet. At first I was thinking maybe `g2` would tell us whether a given integer was even or odd, but that's definitely not the case. The only other thing I'm thinking is maybe it returns `1` for powers of 2 and `0` for non-powers of 2. That would sort of be a weird function tho. Let's keep going to find out

```
g2(5) => f2(g2(4), g1(5))
      => f2(1, [1,0,1])
      => 0

g2(6) => f2(g2(5), g1(6))
      => f2(0, [0,1,1])
      => f2(1, [1,1])
      => 0

g2(7) => f2(g2(6), g1(7))
      => f2(0, [1,1,1])
      => 1

g2(8) => f2(g2(7), g1(8))
      => f2(1, [0,0,0,1])
      => f2(0, [0,0,1])
      => f2(1, [0,1])
      => f2(0, [1])
      => 1
```

**An unexpected pattern emerges**

OK, so we've reached `g2(7) == 1` and `g2(8) == 1`. Our power-of-2 theory definitely didn't pan out, but that's OK as we can see another pattern has emerged - `g2` will return `1` if the bit sequence contains an odd number of `1`s and it will return `0` if the bit sequence contains an even number of `1`s.

I made a little truth table here to check my guess

```
g1(0) => [0]          ones(0) => 0    odd?(ones(0)) => 0    g2(0) => 0
g1(1) => [1]          ones(1) => 1    odd?(ones(1)) => 1    g2(1) => 1
g1(2) => [0,1]        ones(2) => 1    odd?(ones(2)) => 1    g2(2) => 1
g1(3) => [1,1]        ones(3) => 2    odd?(ones(3)) => 0    g2(3) => 0
g1(4) => [0,0,1]      ones(4) => 1    odd?(ones(4)) => 1    g2(4) => 1
g1(5) => [1,0,1]      ones(5) => 2    odd?(ones(5)) => 0    g2(5) => 0
g1(6) => [0,1,1]      ones(6) => 2    odd?(ones(6)) => 0    g2(6) => 0
g1(7) => [1,1,1]      ones(7) => 3    odd?(ones(7)) => 1    g2(7) => 1
g1(8) => [0,0,0,1]    ones(8) => 1    odd?(ones(8)) => 1    g2(8) => 1
```

So `g2(x)` is equivalent to `odd?ones(x)`, at least where `0 <= x <= 8`. Evaluating `g2(0)` thru `g2(8)` took about 10 minutes, and analysing the pattern took maybe 5-10 more minutes, for a running total of around 25 minutes. But now we know everything it takes to evaluate `g(256)` and `g(257)` without doing all the tedious, step-by-step recursion

**The code has been cracked**

Converting 256 to binary, we know `g1(256)` is `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`, likewise `g1(257)` is `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]` so it's easy to compute `g2(256)` and compare it to `g(257)` now

```
g1(256) => [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]    ones(256) => 1    odd?(ones(256)) => 1    g2(256) => 1
g1(257) => [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]    ones(257) => 2    odd?(ones(257)) => 0    g2(257) => 0
```

And that's all of it

```
g2(7) => 1
g2(8) => 1
g2(256) => 1
g2(257) => 0
```

Add a couple minutes for this and we should be right around 30 minutes - give or take 50% depending on proficiency and ability to recognize patterns.

---

**Pick a pattern, any pattern**

Oh and um, maybe you find a different pattern – that's totally OK! What matters is that you truth-check it to the best of your ability (keeping in mind your time constraints).

> `f2` inverts bit `b` as many times as the number of 0's before the first 1 in the list `s`.

I see that you have some understanding of `f2` but it's a little problematic because `b` is initially equal to `g2(n - 1)`. Say we want to compute `f2(b, s)` where `b` is `g2(1234)`... we're stuck because we don't know what that is yet. Unfortunately, this is a dead-end observation of `f2`

That's why it helps that I was able to (or got lucky enough to) establish a correlation between `g1` and `g2` for *known* inputs that's completely irrelevant of `f1` or `f2`. Once I was able to see how `g1` and `g2` were working, I didn't even have to compute `f1` or `f2` to evaluate `g(256)` and `g(257)`. This is a tremendous gain because I effectively cut `f1` and `f2` out of my pen & paper evaluation model and still arrived at correct answers for `g1` and `g2`. Without reaching this point, I would've been stuck searching for another correlation or manually evaluating all the way up to `g(257)` ... which would've take way too long for the exam.

Comment: This is, by no means, a trivial problem. I had a good deal of intuition going into it, but hopefully your textbook or teacher is equipping you with techniques to approach these problems in an effective manner. One of the big things I use to dissect a recursive function is start with an input value that causes the least computation (eg like we did with `g1(0)`) – then continue by finding the next input that would be the easiest to compute (in our case, it was `g1(1)` because we already knew the result of `g1(0)`)

Comment: I used this same technique for dismantling `g2` and luckily it worked – sometimes it does and other times you might need to try approaching the function in another way. Either way, for this particular problem, I think a novice programmer should be able to make sense of the relationship formed by 4 functions within 30-60 minutes. If you have any other questions, I'm happy to help to the best of my ability ^_^

Comment: This is a great answer; I really appreciate the effort you put into this. I was doing the inefficient thing of working the functions bottom up but this not only quicker but also increases clarity. Thanks a lot.